# koa-static: async function isn't supported by old Node.js

Tags: javascript, babeljs, koa

In my Koa project, I use the `koa-static` to serve the static files. And the simple project it just goes as following:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var serve = require('koa-static');
var app = new koa();
app.use(serve('./public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

We plan to put all the static files in the `public` folder.

But I get the following error message when I want to run the Node app.

> ```
> koa-static@4.0.1@koa-static\index.js:39
> return async function serve (ctx, next) {
>              ^^^^^^^^
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
> ```

So my Node version is `6.11.0`. And the `koa-static` used `async/await` function, which is supported by Node.js newer than v7.6.0.

So if I don't plan to update the Node, is there anyway to work around this issue? I manually use `Babel` to transpile my ES6 code. But for the package, can I babel it?

Comment: Transpile with babel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that Koa is specifically built around `async/await` and Node.js 7.6.0 or higher, which is mentioned at [GitHub](https://github.com/koajs/koa#installation). So package developers are just following the basic standard and most of the time do not bother supporting earlier versions of Node.js. Maybe you should reconsider migrating?

If absolutely not, there are two visible ways to make it work:

1. Setup package.json step to give you transpile with Babel as part of installation process (`npm install` has `preinstall` and `postinstall` steps). That way you will have transpiled packages right after installation.
2. Configure your Webpack (Gulp, Grunt) to preprocess `node_modules` or specifically `koa-static` with Babel. Performance degradation could be significant, and this is rather lazy solution.